# checking whether an object is a boost python object from python

Tags: python, c++, boost

Is there a way I can test to see if an object is a boost class from within python by using the `isinstance` function?

I can see this visually doing something like `object.__class__.__mro__`, which will return something like `(_user_library.SomeCppClass, Boost.Python.instance, object)`

I couldn't figure out how to test this though in code, since I'm not sure where to import `Boost.Python.class` from.